# Reshape of dataset (Time Series) after filtering?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time-series, sktime

i am using HampelFilter to detect outliers by SKTIME on my dataset but i faced a problem after applied the filter . My dataset contains Timeseries (signals) the size of my dataset array is (1, 167) while each one of the 167 elements contain 9000 samples.

[original data imported from .mat file to python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXxp4.png)

i wrote this code to apply the HampelFilter on each elements on one raw as following:-

```
def Hampel(H):
    return HampelFilter(window_length=10).fit_transform(H)
My_Data= data[0,:]

filterd_My_Data=[]
for H in My_Data:
    a=Hampel(H)
    filterd_My_Data.append(a)
```

Before filtering: the shape of it is **(1, 167)** and its type is **'numpy.ndarray'**. same like in next code below :-

```
[array([[0.31494141],
        [0.30151367],
        [0.30395508],
        ...,
        [0.3125    ],
        [0.31738281],
        [0.3112793 ]]) array([[0.30151367],
                              [0.30883789],
                              [0.29907227],
                              ...,
                              [0.31738281],
                              [0.36132812],
                              [0.31738281]]) array([[0.29541016],
                                                    [0.29663086],
                                                    [0.29296875],
                                                    ...,
                                                    [0.28686523],
                                                    [0.29907227],
                                                    [0.29663086]])
 array([[0.31616211],
        [0.3112793 ],
        [0.30273438],
        ...,
        [0.31494141],
        [0.32958984],
        [0.3137207 ]]) array([[0.28442383],
                              [0.28930664],
                              [0.28442383],
                              ...,
                              [0.30029297],
                              [0.30151367],
                              [0.31494141]]) array([[0.30761719],
                                                    [0.31005859],
                                                    [0.30639648],
                                                    ...,
                                                    [0.32836914],
                                                    [0.30761719],
                                                    [0.30273438]])
```

After filtering: it became a **'list'** (its length is 167), while the input was **'numpy.ndarray'**. same like in next code below :-

```
[array([[       nan],
       [0.30151367],
       [0.30395508],
       ...,
       [0.3125    ],
       [0.31738281],
       [0.3112793 ]]), array([[0.30151367],
       [0.30883789],
       [0.29907227],
       ...,
       [0.31738281],
       [       nan],
       [0.31738281]]), array([[0.29541016],
       [0.29663086],
       [0.29296875],
       ...,
```

then i convert the list to an array and i got a flat array its shape became **(167, 9000,1)**.

```
[[[       nan]
  [0.30151367]
  [0.30395508]
  ...
  [0.3125    ]
  [0.31738281]
  [0.3112793 ]]

 [[0.30151367]
  [0.30883789]
  [0.29907227]
  ...
  [0.31738281]
  [       nan]
  [0.31738281]]

 [[0.29541016]
  [0.29663086]
  [0.29296875]
  ...
  [0.28686523]
  [0.29907227]
  [0.29663086]]

 ...
```

The code works very well and it removed all the outliers but i can not add the new array to my dataset because it did not match the shape.

now My array shape is (167,9000) I want to change it to (167,1), only one element contains all the samples of time series.

**How can i return the shape array after converting as before?? or
How can i let one element of an array contain some elements??**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Very good that you elaborated your question and provided some code. I personally appreciate it if one strips not only its code but also the data to create a [minimum viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that one can run code out of the box without downloading bulky files =) Anyway, looks like you have a `numpy.reshape` problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal before and after filtering is of same length and you append multiple signals (of length 9000) so you get a 167-long list of signals that are 9000 points long. Why are you expecting to get a 1D array? You get a list of lists ...

```py
import numpy as np
from sktime.transformations.series.outlier_detection import HampelFilter

# toy filter function
def hampel_filter(sig):  # it is good style to save upper- and camel-case names for classes
    return HampelFilter().fit_transform(sig)

# generate toy data
data = np.random.rand(1, 3, 90)  # shape(data): (1, 3, 90)
print(f'np.shape(data.shape): {data.shape}')

mydata = data[0, :]  # shape(mydata): (3, 90)
print(f'shape(mydata): {mydata.shape}')

mydata_filtered = []
for signal in mydata:  # shape(signal): (90, 1) => this is a 2D array! (a vector)
    print(f'shape(signal): {np.shape(signal)}')
    signal_filtered = hampel_filter(signal)
    mydata_filtered.append(signal_filtered)
print(f'shape(mydata_filtered): {np.shape(mydata_filtered)}')
```

and you'll get:

```sh
np.shape(data.shape): (1, 3, 90)
shape(mydata): (3, 90)
shape(signal): (90,)
shape(signal): (90,)
shape(signal): (90,)
shape(mydata_filtered): (3, 90, 1)
```

you can `flatten` the filtered signal in the `hampel_filter` if you need to have an array returned, you would get:

```sh
np.shape(data.shape): (1, 3, 90)
shape(mydata): (3, 90)
shape(signal): (90,)
shape(signal): (90,)
shape(signal): (90,)
shape(mydata_filtered): (3, 90)
```